# How to pass different File paths to one autoit scripts using java dynamically

Tags: selenium, file-upload, autoit

2

I have one scenario which i need upload a file from desktop window.

I am using autoit script.it is working fine when i hardcoded filepath in autoit script.

I have 100 scenarios to upload different files.so i need to write 100 autoit scripts.

can anyone help how to use one autoit script for all scenarios taking file path dyanmically using java,

Please anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: This is the auto it script which worked for me for uploading a single file....     Is there any other code for uploading multiple files using autoit dynamically taking the files names in a loop?                                                  WinActivate("Open")
Send("C:\Selenium\AutoIt_Scripts\Returns_Regression.xls")
Send("{ENTER}")

Comment: take from where? From parameters or all files from a defined location?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your Autoitscript via call from Java, then have a look at the commandline parameters.

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm

You could start your Autoitscript and send the filepath(s) via commandline parameter.
Doesn't matter if you start an autoitscript.exe or autoitscript.au3 file. Both ways are possible.

Another option would be hardcode the path to an ini file in your script and before startintg the script, set the path in the ini to your upload-file via Java and then start the script. Then you do not need any parameter in your Autoit-script at all.

Have a look at IniRead : https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IniRead.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use Java process builder and CmdLine (AutoIT).

You need to do something like this in order to provide a dynamic path to the file whenever you executing .exe file.

**Considering you have the following script:**

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","YOUR CONTROL")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","D:\\folder\\new_folder\\file_1.png")
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

**You need to update the setText command and your AutoIT script should look like this:**

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","YOUR CONTROL")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

save and compile your file here then you can do this code in your Java class:

```
String pathToAIExe = System.getProperty("user.dir") + ExeFilePath;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        String uploadFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\path_to_files\\file_"+i+".extension";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pathToAIExe, uploadFilePath);
        pb.start();
    }
```

Here parameter **"uploadFilePath"** in java code is the first parameter in the Java process builder against CmdLine[1]/ first variable that you have defined in your AutoIT compiled file.